# iPhone:How open two safari browser tab with two link on button action in iphone?

Tags: ios, ios4

If i have two url which i want to open simultaneously on two different safari tab on a button click ,how can i call the open url? or is there any other method is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to open multiple tabs from your application. I guess there are multiple reasons for this, including usability and a potential for spamming.

If you want to open a single tab here is the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])

NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

If you want to open multiple webpages, I suggest you direct the user to a webpage where they are able to find links to both of these pages.